# Null pointer inside stub?

Tags: axis, stub

I am getting this really strange message from my stub (and it doesn't happen often but sometimes, few times a day):

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/EWC] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.company.rewsapi.REWSStub.isUserValid(REWSStub.java:28915)
at com.company.rews.webclient.beans.ClientBeanBase.isUserConnectedToREWS(ClientBeanBase.java:152)
```

The line 28915 inside the `stub` is:

```
_messageContext.getTransportOut().getSender().cleanup(_messageContext);
```

I never get null pointers from within stub. How can this happen?

What do I need to do to trace the error or to reproduce it so I can debug?

Answer (score 0):

separate this 
`_messageContext.getTransportOut().getSender().cleanup(_messageContext);` 
line into

```
TransportOut to = _messageContext.getTransportOut();
Sender sender = to.getSender();
sender.cleanup(_messageContext);
```

Compile and run. During execution if any NullPointerException occures, you will clearly get what is null then identify why that is null.

Comment: Hmm... I can't do that because stub is automatically generated code?

Comment: OK, tried it, edited stub. Error is on the first line:          `TransportOutDescription to = _messageContext.getTransportOut();` So, `_messageContext` becomes `null`. Any idea why would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

looks like the apache fix was

```
} finally {
   if (_messageContext.getTransportOut() != null) {
       _messageContext.getTransportOut().getSender().cleanup(_messageContext);
   }
}
```

fixed in 1.6.0 or 1.5.5 streams via

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-3788

Comment: Which version of Apache fixes this?